# Detection element by letters title

Tags: java, intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver

```
private String emailTitle = "Gmail " + System.currentTimeMillis();
WebElement emailLink =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='+emailTitle+')]"));
emailLink.click();
```

Problem with finding the letter with specific title. Please help to know how to make right

Comment: Your question seems to be vague. Please, clarify your question first.

Answer (score 0):

can you try below one. am using "containstext" method to find the element

```
emailLink=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), '"+emailTitle+"')]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to insert variable to string is

```
"//span[text()='" + emailTitle + "')]"
```